# How to create a temporary table by passing in data to psycopg2?

Tags: psycopg2

I have a pandas dataframe that I want to pass into a psycopg2 `execute` statement as a temporary table. This should be very simple:

pseudo-code...

```
string = """
  with temporary_table (id, value) as (values %s)

  select * from temporary_table
"""
cur.execute(string, df)
```

Where `df` is just a dataframe with an `id` and `value` column.

What would be the syntax to use such that I'd be able to pass this data in as a temporary table and use it in my query?

Comment: A `df` is a Panda object and cannot be used directly as a source of values in `execute`. You will need to use [to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). Probably two part script: 1) Create temp table 2) Use `to_sql` to populate it in same session. Otherwise you will need to pull data out of `df` as say a `dict` and use that.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes sorry I see the confusion, but I'm aware that passing a pandas dataframe into sql doesn't make sense... the way I'm currently doing it is converting the dataframe into a tuple of tuples, converting that to a string, and then removing the first and last `(` and `)` with string clipping, and passing in the string as a variable that gets replaced at `%s`, I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant way of doing it, if so, please expand on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A test case that I think does what you want:

```python
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432")

sql_str = """WITH temporary_table (
    id,
    value
) AS (
    VALUES %s
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    temporary_table
"""
cur = con.cursor()
execute_values(cur, sql_str, ((1, 2), (2,3)))
cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Using `execute_values` from [Fast Execution Helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

**UPDATE**

Sticking to just `execute`:

```python
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres host=localhost port=5432")
cur = con.cursor()

input_data = ((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))

sql_str = sql.SQL("""WITH temporary_table (
    id,
    value
) AS (
    VALUES {}
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    temporary_table
""").format(sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(input_data)))

cur.execute(sql_str, input_data)

cur.fetchall()                                                                                                                                                            
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Can you do this exact same thing, just without `execute_values`? For reasons not worth explaining, I can't use that function.

Comment: What can you use e.g. `execute_batch` or `execute_many`?

Comment: My question is just specifically about doing this with `cur.execute`

Comment: See **UPDATE** that  uses `execute`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary table in Postgres database with df.to_sql or execute insert sql query with values, query it and at the end of process delete it